# Check if the text 'ABC' is there it should be preceded and succeeded by a numeric only, followed by a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which should fail for the below

> 1. text1 abc
> 2. abc 1ed1
> 3. text1 abc 1ed1

It should only pass the structures like

> 1. 11231 abc 23435

Format: xxx abc yyy

> xxx, yyy = digits only of any length
>
> abc = Fixed string, it should be ignored if not appeared. If appeared, it should be in specific format.

I have tried the below regex. It passes if preceded and succeeded without any single digit only. But no luck with the above issues.

```
\b((\D+[ ]\bABC\b)|(\bABC\b[ ]\D+))
```

*DETAILS FROM CHAT*:

I don't have a string exactly. It's a user input. When the input value will contain something like 'abc' we should expect a numeric in both the sides. Else when it doesn't contain 'abc' we are good (may be some other validations).

Few examples :

```
123 abc (match) 
abc 1234 (match) 
xyz abc (match) 
abc xyz (match) 
xyz32 abc xyz23 (match) 
xyz32 abc 34523 (match) 
1234 abc xyz23 (match) 
12322 abc 1111(pass, we are good).
```

All can be a sub-string, but new words i.e. not a part of the word

Comment: Try `/\b\d+ ABC \d+\b/i`

Answer (score 0):

`\d+\sabc+\s\d+`

See https://regex101.com/r/gxgEGH/1 for explanation

Answer (score 0):

`\b\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\b`

```js
console.log('text1 abc abc 1ed1 text1 abc 1ed1 11231 abc 23435'.match(/\b\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\b/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that with pure regex in JS as it does not support an infinite width lookbehind that would be necessary to check if `abc` is not preceded with a whole word consisting of only digits. A working approach can be the following: use an alternation group to capture the `abc` within digits as whole words, and just match other cases where `abc` is a whole word. Then, check if the capture group matched, and if it did you have no match. Else, you have a match.

```
/\b(\d+ abc \d+)\b|\babc\b/
```

*Details*:

- `\b(\d+` - a leading word boundary (there can be start of string or a non-word char before) 1+ digits (also, start of Group 1)
- `abc`  - `abc` hard-coded value with spaces around
- `\d+)\b` - 1+ digits followed with a trailing word boundary (no word chars - letters, digits or underscores - can appear after these digits) (end of Group 1)
- `|` - or
- `\babc\b` - a whole word `abc`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/liZELd/1). Note that last match also contains a capture group #1.

```js
var regex = /\b(\d+ abc \d+)\b|\babc\b/;
var strs = ['123 abc', 'abc 1234', 'xyz abc', 'abc xyz', 'xyz32 abc xyz23', 'xyz32 abc 34523', '1234 abc xyz23', '12322 abc 1111'];
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  var m = strs[i].match(regex);
  if (m && m[1])
    console.log(strs[i] + " is FALSE");
  else if (m)
    console.log(strs[i] + " is TRUE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. You got it right. But, I just need the reverse.
I will blacklist when there is 'abc' with condition not satisfied. I can't just whitelist the condition as I have some other checks. Please advise, if you have an answer.

Comment: Do still need to extract some chunks of text from a larger one or validate separate strings?

Comment: I mean, if I get a match like 'test11 abc' or 'abc 1test' or 'test1 abc 1test'.. I have to block, else I am good. Thanks

Comment: Try [`/[^\d\s]\d* abc\b|\babc \d*[^\d\s]/`](https://regex101.com/r/gxgEGH/3). If these must be matched if the optional digits are followed/preceded with other word chars other than digits, replace `[^\d\s]` with `[a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: This one is awesome.. Thanks
But again it doesn't recognize 'abc 56' & '56 abc'. I will need the digit in both the sides... any one side should be captured as well :(

Comment: Try [`(^|[^\d\s])\d* abc\b|\babc \d*([^\d\s]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/gxgEGH/4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124938/discussion-between-arun-pati-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please see the updated answer based on the chat talk.